# Force a form input in uppercase - onChange and React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I would like to force a form input in uppercase.

I use an `onChange` method and React Hooks, but it doesn't work and I don't know why... It's pretty basic, but I'm React beginner.

I imported my Redux store on a higher component: `props name -> "facture"`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Col, Row } from 'mdmrc/lib/components/grid'
import { Button } from 'mdmrc/lib/components/button'
import { Form } from 'mdmrc/lib/components/form'
import { Input } from 'mdmrc/lib/components/input'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

/**
 * composant de mise à jour des données de la facture
 */
export const UpdateForm = ({ classes, onSubmit, facture }) => {
  // ajout de la traduction
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  const [codePaysValue, setCodePaysValue] = useState(
    facture.codePays ? facture.codePays : ''
  )

  const handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    setCodePaysValue(value)
  }

  /**
   * Controle de surface du formulaire d'update
   */
  const validationOptions = {
    some code here...
  }

  return (
    <Col span={12} className={classes.updateForm}>
      <Form
        id="update-form"
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        validationOptions={validationOptions}
        defaultValues={{
          codePays: codePaysValue ? codePaysValue : '',
        }}
      >
        <Row>
          <Col span={8}>
            <label>{t('updateForm.codePays')}</label>
          </Col>
          <Col span={16}>
            <Input
              type="text"
              maxLength={2}
              name="codePays"
              id="codePays"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Button type="primary" style={{ width: '100%' }} htmlType="submit">
          {t('updateForm.enregistrer')}
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Col>
```

No console errors. But my code is always in lowercase if I don't use uppercase letters.

Answer (score 8):

Here i'm using a homemade library created by my company (based on Ant Design) and  is in a FORM.item wrapper. So i just found the problem : I have to use normalize props. Exemple :

```
<Form>
    <Input
        type="text"
        maxLength={2}
        name="codePays"
        id="codePays"
        normalize={value => (value || '').toUpperCase()}
    />
</Form>
```

Answer (score 6):

In your code, you are not using **value field** or some other attribute for value for Input. See in the `prop type` definition for `Input` component of the library used.

```
<Input
  type="text"
  maxLength={2}
  name="codePays"
  id="codePays"
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={codePaysValue}
/>
```

For reference - Simple example of using hooks for upper-casing input value.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const changeHandler = ({ target }) => {
    setValue(target.value.toUpperCase())
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type='text' value={value} onChange={changeHandler}></input>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Your answer is true. But here <input> is in a Form.Item wrapper. Just need normalize props. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tomakazub - I also thought it had to be custom library and attribute field could differ. Good you were able to figure that out. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, I had the same question. In the end I found a shorter solution which is to simply call the toUpperCase() method.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
...

return (
  ...
  <Input type='text' value={value.toUpperCase()} />
);
```

The form input will automatically display in uppercase as you type.

Comment: why do we need to set the const value first if we just need to visually change to uppercase?